# CKAN exposing tables from a relational database

Tags: metadata, ckan

I am using CKAN 2.3 and I would like to compose datasets considering a specific schema from a relational database. Indeed, I would like to publish the list of any table into CKAN in order to show which kind of data I have stored in Oracle.

I know that there are some harvesting extensions but if I am not wrong it seems no one is useful to configure a connection to Oracle's database getting a collection of all tables.

Does anybody know if there's any helpful extension for this purpose or any way to do it easily?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried the resources here?

https://lists.okfn.org/mailman/listinfo/ckan-dev

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Hyon. Yes, I tried long time ago but I got no answer. Here is the link to my **okfn** petition: [link](https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2015-April/008901.html)